# Error while building app in cross-compiled qt in raspberry

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling

I'm trying to build and app on a cross-compiled `qt5` in a raspberry pi.
This app is based on this `rf24l01` [library](https://github.com/stanleyseow/RF24). When I compile a `cpp` program from the RPi, everything works fine, but when I tried from my pc running `ubuntu 12.04 (32bits)` the following error is through:

```
error: cannot find -lrf24-bcm
```

I point to the library using this line in the pro file:

```
LIBS += -L/mnt/rpi/usr/local/lib -lrf24-bcm
```

AFAIK, this is the path where the lib is located:

This is the result of `ls /mnt/rpi/usr/local/lib:

```
librf24-bcm.so      libwiringPiDev.so      libwiringPi.so.2.0
librf24-bcm.so.1    libwiringPiDev.so.2.0  python2.6
librf24-bcm.so.1.0  libwiringPi.so         python2.7
```

Finally, this is the appeared error in detail:

> /home/atron/opt/gcc-4.7-linaro-rpi-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -Wl,-rpath-
> link,/mnt/rpi/opt/vc/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,/mnt/rpi/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -Wl,-rpath-
> link,/mnt/rpi/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf --sysroot=/mnt/rpi -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/opt/lib -o homekit main.o   -L/mnt/rpi/usr/local/lib -lrf24-bcm -L/mnt/rpi/usr/local/opt/lib -lQt5Network -L/usr/local/opt/lib -lQt5Core -lpthread 
> /home/atron/opt/gcc-4.7-linaro-rpi-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.7.2/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lrf24-bcm
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

What I`m doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is "technically" correct, but solved my problem.
The main idea is create a symbolic link of the library to my pc `/usr/local/lib` folder:

```
sudo ln -s /mnt/rpi/usr/local/lib/librf24-bcm.so /usr/local/lib/librf24-bcm.so
sudo ln -s /mnt/rpi/usr/local/lib/librf24-bcm.so.1 /usr/local/lib/librf24-bcm.so.1
sudo ln -s /mnt/rpi/usr/local/lib/librf24-bcm.so.1.0 /usr/local/lib/librf24-bcm.so.1.0
```

Then, on QT creator `*pro` file you only need to add the lib reference:

```
LIBS=-lrf24-bcm
```

I hope this could help to some newbie like me.
Regards,