# "Illegal instruction" when trying to run cross-compiled Qt on Raspberry Pi (Windows)

Tags: c++, qt, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling, toolchain

I have found and read the [question here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7541/how-to-solve-qt5-illegal-instruction-issue-in-cross-compilation), also threads [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621393/illegal-instruction-when-cross-compiling-qt-4-7) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27476483/error-while-building-app-in-cross-compiled-qt-in-raspberry), unfortunately it still remains unresolved. *(though I used all the tips from that thread to give as much info as I can)*

---

### What's the problem

For a few days I've been trying to find a way to bo able to cross-compile **Qt** , as I got one recently and now wanted to learn how to code some basic embedded apps.

**I'm following the tutorial here:** http://visualgdb.com/tutorials/raspberry/qt/embedded/

- I used a clean system, the only thing I had to install were some depedencies: `apt-get install libudev-dev libinput-dev libts-dev libxcb*`(running it for the first time, `configure` was saying about missing
  libs)
- Got Raspbian image and toolchain from [here](http://gnutoolchains.com/raspberry/), respectively `2015-11-21-raspbian-jessie` and `raspberry-gcc-4.9.2-r2.exe`
- Qt source also comes from the link in the tutorial above (`qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.0.tar.xz`)
- I used the same file paths etc, so all the commands should be fine, including the configure: `../qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.0/configure -platform win32-g++ -xplatform linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -release -opengl es2 -device linux-rasp-pi2-g++ -sysroot C:/SysGCC/Raspberry/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot -prefix /usr/local/qt5 -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=C:/SysGCC/Raspberry/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf- -qt-xcb`

After several hours everything were built, presumably without errors. (my output was more less the same as on the screenshots in the tutorial)

**However, trying to run any of the examples built, results in just one line:** `Illegal instruction`

---

### What more can I provide...

- Following [the thread I mentioned at the beginning](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/7542), here's the `file` output:

  ```
  root@raspberrypi:/usr/local/qt5/examples/opengl/cube# file cube

  cube: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically
  linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32,
  BuildID[sha1]=e4c51318d4ca583ace647510c9b4cddd06a34e19, stripped
  ```
- I tried to run the app with ***gdb*** using `gdb ./cube` and then `run`. The output is:

  ```
  (gdb) run
  Starting program: /usr/local/qt5/examples/opengl/cube/cube 
  [Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
  Using host libthread_db library "/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libthread_db.so.1".

  Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
  0xb6249734 in QMutex::lock() () from /usr/local/qt5/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
  (gdb) Quit
  ```
- The compiler itself work as cross-compile - I'm able to build C++ Hello World on windows, compile using `C:\SysGCC\Raspberry\bin\arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++.exe` and then run it on Raspberry
- I was even able to configure Qt Creator properly, using `arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++.exe` as a compiler and `C:\SysGCC\Raspberry\arm-linux-gnueabihf\sysroot\usr\local\qt5\bin\qmake.exe` as **qmake** - **Basic opengl project builds fine, even remote deploying to raspi works :)** ... pity about the "Illegal instruction"
- Raspbian: `Linux raspberrypi 4.1.19+ #858 Tue Mar 15 15:52:03 GMT 2016 armv6l GNU/Linux`

  ```
  root@raspberrypi:/# lsb_release -a
  No LSB modules are available.
  Distributor ID: Raspbian
  Description: Raspbian GNU/Linux 8.0 (jessie)
  Release: 8.0
  Codename: jessie
  ```
- Windows 7 64 bit

---

Thanks in advance for any help. Of course I would give any necessary info if needed.

*Seriously, I'm trying for a week, already failed with linux-like stuff on [wiki.qt.io](https://wiki.qt.io/RaspberryPi_Beginners_Guide) [wiki.qt.io](https://wiki.qt.io/Native_Build_of_Qt5_on_a_Raspberry_Pi) **Still, I'm really looking forward to make a robust, cross-compile, remote-deploy Qt environment for future developing on my Raspberry from Windows :)***

Comment: Hey man keep us posted if you find a solution, I have the same here cross-compiling from Linux using this tutorial: https://wiki.qt.io/RaspberryPi2EGLFS

Comment: You can try to run raspi-config on your raspi and then "Advanced Options" -> "GL Driver". I wasn't able to enable the GL driver, as it was not supported by the device, which lead me to checking the version number printed on the board. The RasPi 1 B+ v1.2 does not work here.

Plugging in my other raspi (2 B v1.1) worked fine then. Well, nothing happens yet when I run the "qopenglwidget" example, but the "Illegal instruction" has gone.

So it might be the wrong RasPi for the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it turned out to be embarrassingly obvious. The tutorial here: http://visualgdb.com/tutorials/raspberry/qt/embedded/ is made for Raspberry Pi 2, although **it's not mentioned explicitly**

Luckily you just need to change configure script from `-device linux-rasp-pi2-g++` to `-device linux-rasp-pi-g++`

I was surprised, but apparently it worked perfectly for me.

So now the configure line should look like this:

```
../qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.0/configure -platform win32-g++ -xplatform linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -release -opengl es2 -device linux-rasp-pi-g++ -sysroot C:/SysGCC/Raspberry/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot -prefix /usr/local/qt5 -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=C:/SysGCC/Raspberry/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf- -qt-xcb
```

Thanks *@Bugfinger* for a hint :)

PS. If you don't know which version of RPi you have (I wasn't sure at all), you can compare specs and peripherals [here](http://elinux.org/RPi_Hardware#Specifications) or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi#Specifications)